# Как выставить несколько блоков в центр

Tags: css

Нужно центрировать следующий блок. Пробовал text-align:center. Класс center c шаблона. Искуственно ставлял в код, разные div c col-md-2, как здесь но не помогло. Помогите плиз.

```
<?php if($value['fourth_name'] != ""){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-2 center"></div>
<?php } else  if($value['third_name'] != ""){ ?>
    <div class="col-md-3 center"></div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div class="col-md-4 center"></div>
<?php } ?>
```

[image: Картина]

Мой код:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .wr {
        display: flex;
    }

    .cen {
        display: flex; 
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 10px;
        -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
        -moz-border-radius: 10px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        border-color: #6fb3e0;
        width: 200px;
        min-height: 350px;
        margin-right: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
        position: relative;
    }

    .btn1 {
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%);
        bottom: 10px;
    }
</style>    

<div class="wr">
    <div class="thumbnail search-thumbnail cen col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2  center">
        <img class="media-object"  src="<?= base_url()?>assets/images/gallery/<?= $value['first_photo'] ?>" >   
        <div class="caption btn1">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <span class="label label-grey info-label"> Голосов: <?= $value['first_sum'] ?></span>
            </div>
            <h3 class="search-title">
                <span class="blue"><?= $value['first_name'] ?></span>
            </h3>
            <?php if(!isset($have) && $time > 0){ ?>
            <div class="center">
                <a class="id-btn-dialog2 btn  btn-info">
                    Голосовать
                </a>

            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="thumbnail search-thumbnail col-xs-6 col-sm-2 col-md-2 cen center">
        <img  src="<?= base_url()?>assets/images/gallery/<?= $value['second_photo'] ?>" >
        <div class="caption btn1">
            <div class="clearfix">
                <span class="label label-grey info-label"> Голосов: <?= $value['second_sum'] ?></span>
            </div>

            <h3 class="search-title">
                <span class="blue"><?= $value['second_name'] ?></span>
            </h3>
            <?php if(!isset($have)  && $time > 0){ ?>
            <div class="center">
                <a class="id-btn-dialog2 btn  btn-success">
                    Голосовать
                </a>
                
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить класс `.cen` к элементу `.wr`, выкладывайте впредь скомпилированный код, пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

```
 .wr {
        display: flex;
        justify-content:center;
    }
```

Вы это имели ввиду ?

Comment: Помогло double thanks